# How to ignore NA when using mean?

Tags: r

1)

```
x=2;y=3
mean(x,y)
#[1] 2
```

I am surprised why 2. It should be 2.5!

2)

```
x=c(2,5,NA)
y=c(3,NA,NA)
mean(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)
Error in mean.default(x, y, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

I want to compute the mean between `x` and `y`. When there is `NA`, just put the other value.

desired output:

```
2.5 5 NA
```

Comment: You can use `mean(c(x,y))`  If you look at the `?mean`, there is only one input vector i.e. `mean(x, ...)`

Comment: `mapply(function(a,b) mean(c(a,b), na.rm = T), x,y)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Concerning your second question, you can try this:

```
> rowMeans(data.frame(x, y), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 2.5 5.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @DavidArenburg It's definitely better and less error-prone to spell out `TRUE`. A bad habit of mine...

Answer (score 6):

Concerning your first question it should be

```
 mean(c(x,y))
```

You could actually define your own mean which fixes this

```
 mymean <- function(...,na.rm=FALSE){mean(c(...),na.rm=na.rm)}
```

**EDIT:** For your second problem see the solution by @RHertel

Comment: @Bazz: Probably pretty tough to keep a programming language consistent. Changing theses things later will break a lot of existing code. That is why designing languages and APIs requires a lot of careful thinking.